# copying word/powerpoint equations into mathematica notebook presentation slides

Tags: formatting, mathematica

I am trying to copy mathematical equations/content that I wrote in Word using the Office equation editor into a Mathematica notebook slide as a Mathematica presentation.

I tried copying the equations as LaTeX or mathML and pasting in Mathematica but it did not work so well; the formatting in mathematica was all wrong.
Apart from starting rewriting the equations from scratch, what other simplifying options are out there? I tried saving as an OpenDocument Presentation, without success. I could try picture file but..really...

Isn't there something to make such natural interoperability transitions smoother?

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work so well"? Did it not come across at all? Could you perhaps post a screenshot?

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: May I suggest to the original poster to consider committing to the Area51 proposal for Mathematica http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15787/mathematica ? This question would be on-topic if that site is approved to be launched.

Comment: @Verbeia Do you participate in any other "niche" SE site? Perhaps they are not as successful as you believe ...

Comment: @belisarius - I saw how few Mma questions there were on superuser, and realised that condensing it all onto a Mma-specific site is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Verbeia I saw other sites emerge and then close b/c the generated traffic was not up to the site owners expectations, so losing all the generated content. I prefer the safety shore.

Comment: I am not that familiar with all the refinements of where to post which type of questions on stackexchange and it seemed to me a question about mathematica formatting issues would be welcomed here. I posted this question before going to bed last night and the intense negativity of responses is just... dispiriting. Why not just ignore if you can't say anything positive/constructive?..BTW i edited the question to make it easy to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Verbeia Area51 looks interesting!

Comment: @Verbeia Area51 looks interesting! it does not seem yet ready for actual questions...

Comment: David Vasholz's gave a presentation about `ImportString[#, "TeX"]&` which is pretty sophisticated solution to interoperating between TeX and Mathematica for typesetting math:
http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference-2011/electronic-publishing.html

Comment: @Phil - no, it's in the "commit" stage. If enough people commit, then the site goes into beta.

Answer (score 5):

Word 2007 as well as all Office 2010 applications support MathML, so you can paste equations directly into Mathematica for as long as you make sure that you only copy the equation parts, but no surrounding text.

In older version of Office the only solution I know is a (vector) picture.  If you copy the equation while in Equation Editor, it'll be pasted to Mathematica as EMF (i.e. high quality scalable, but not editable)

Comment: that is eactly what i do and it does not work. In the equations editor, there is a cut and copy preferences bot where you choose the the format you want your equations copied. I have chosen the various forms of latex and MathML offered with no apparent success...Anyway at this point it may just be simpler to rewrite everything in mathematica...

Comment: @Phil, what sort of equation editor do you use, with what version of Office?  It sounds like it's not the standard one that comes with Office.

Comment: +1 For the hint on pasting metafiles - I was unaware of this. One note: for pasting a Metafile one needs to create a Cell first (this is why I had not discovered this functionality earlier). I am not sure whether the inserted metafile is EMF or [WMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile). I thought earlier that WMF is default under Windows but it may be version and/or application-dependent.

Comment: @Phil If you use MathType you could just open an equation in MathType and then copy it from it, then paste in *Mathematica*. Works at least starting from MathType 6.